# Change Background of Notification Dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, notifications

Demo page code below. I make a smart notification. I can see that in the CSS it is set to background black, I try to dynamically change this on creation to a different colour, it works when I do this in the inspector, but not in code. Any help appreciated ( I am basically trying to make it the black initial notification a random colour).

```
// With Input
    $('.MessageBoxContainer').css({backgroundColor: 'red'}); 
    // This is what I try to change colour, des not work

    $.SmartMessageBox({
        title : "Welcome to the Clevertree demonstration.",
        content : "Please enter your name to continue",
        buttons : "[Accept]",
        input : "text"


    },



        function(ButtonPress, name) {
        //alert(Value);
        $( ".chosen_name" ).html(name);

        $.ajax({
            'url' : 'http://clevertree.co.uk/index.php/site/blankadd',
            'type' : 'POST', //the way you want to send data to your URL
            'data': {
                name: name
            },
            'async': false,
            'success' : function(data){ //probably this request will return anything, it'll be put in var "data"
                if(data){

                    userInfo = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    //userInfo.User_ID
                    //alert(userInfo.User_ID);

                  $('.MessageBoxContainer').css({backgroundColor: 'red'}); 
    // I try again here, still does not work
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like below to change css color

```
$('.MessageBoxContainer').css('background-color','yellow');
```

See jsfiddle here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/24XE2/3/

Can you paste your html as well

Comment: Thanks. That is all the code really to generate the dialog. I don't call anything in HTML. That code above is called automatically when the page loads. What could I put in the javascript to change the colour of it, without editing the CSS (as I want some black ones still as well)?